# A new error I never seen before in Android. Is there any Solution?

Tags: android

```
02-07 10:49:45.558: E/dalvikvm-gc(7184): Could not create 2617344-byte ashmem mark stack: Too many open files
```

While I was playing the game and after some time the game forced closed showing the above error in Log Cat. Is there any solution for this?? and what could be its cause??

Answer (score 2):

The cause is that your code is not closing files and the system is running out of file handles. You should always use files using a coding pattern that ensures that all streams are closed when no longer needed. Here's a typical pattern:

```
InputStream is = null;
try {
    is = new FileInputStream(myFile);
    // read stuff from is
} finally {
    if (is != null) {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Exception raised when closing file", e);
        }
    }
}
```

The outer `try` could also have a `catch` clause. The reason for the `try/catch` in the `finally` clause is to prevent an exception in closing the file from suppressing any exception raised in the outer `try` block.

Writing to files tends to be less of a problem because programmers usually take care to close the file to ensure that the data reaches the file. However, a similar pattern should be followed there: never let an exception prevent the closing of a file.

Comment: but the problem is I haven't used any traditional file handling in my code. All I used is shared preferences. Should I wrap them in try catch?

Comment: @JawadAmjad - Are you using any third-party libraries that might be opening files? Any network connections? Any data bases?

Comment: yes I am using but not in the activity which crashes. Its the main game scene where the error occurred I used the libraries in MainMenu.

Comment: @JawadAmjad - It's hard to suggest a specific fix without knowing more about your code. You might try using a tool like [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) to analyze your code. It is easy to use and can find many cases where a stream might be left open.